# Memory based decisions in NetLogo

Tags: memory, netlogo

Hello generous people,

I am writing a model for farmer's decision making based on last period crop production. Initially land parcels (small or large) make farmer to use either of ground or surface water. In later ticks farmer will decide using type of water groundwater or surfacewater based on crop production. A high level of crop production makes farmers to have a memory more than a number X for instance and if memory is higher than X; farmer will choose to follow the strategy he has used to obtain higher crop. I am unable understand that how memory of a farmer will be build to use as an input in the same loop/ code block which I have written for initial yield. Experts on board please extend your help.

```
  Globals [ surface-water surface-water  maximum-yield water-demand  water-used ]
Turtle-own [ yield memory]
to setup
  clear-all
  create 5 [ set yield 0
    set memory 0
  set surface-water 10
  set maximum yield 60
  set groundwater 20
  set water-demand 17
  set land random 5 + 3]
  reset-ticks
end

    to go 
      tick
      ask turtles with land >= 4 [ ifelse random 1 = 0 [set  groundwater-use groundwater - water-demand 
                                                        set yield 0.8 * maximum-yield
                                                        set memory  % of yield   ]
                                                       [ set groundwater-use  0.5 * water-demand 
                                                       set surfacewater-use groundwater-use  0.5 * water-demand
                                                         set yield 0.85 * maximum-yield 
                                                         set memory  % of yield]
      ask  ask turtles with land < 4 [ set groundwater-use  0.5 * water-demand 
                                       set surfacewater-use groundwater-use  0.5 * water-demand
                                                         set yield 0.85 * maximum-yield 
                                                         set memory  % of yield]
    end
```

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand your question. If you create two variables for each farmer that store the best ever yield and the strategy used to achieve that yield, does that answer your question?

Comment: I think yes. how it will be written/ incorporated?

Comment: You need to try and write some code yourself and we can help you fix it if it doesn't work. But the general idea is to have two variables in the `farmers-own` (such as best-yield and best-strategy) and then update them if the yield this tick is better than the current value of best-yield.